# How can I install unique_identifier package?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to install turtlebot based on the instructions stated here "http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation", (section 2.3.2).

However, when I want to catkin_make rocon I get this Error "Messages depends on unknown pkg: uuid_msgs (Missing
find_package(uuid_msgs?))".

Unfortunately, "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-uuid_msgs" or "sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-unique_identifier" give
Unable to locate package ros-indigo...

I appreciate if you can help me.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228057/how-can-i-install-unique_identifier-package?/) by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`uuid_msgs` is [released](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=uuid) into ROS Indigo.

You have the install command wrong. This needs to be:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-uuid-msgs ros-indigo-unique-identifier
```

Note that all underscores (`_`) have been replaced by dashes (`-`)!

You can also install all specified (i.e. it depends on the `package.xml`s being correct) dependencies via:

```
rosdep install --from-paths <catkin_ws/src> -i
```

---

**EDIT**

You need to have your sources set up correctly.
Follow [the instructions on the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu), especially 1.1-1.3, and then do a `sudo apt-get update`.

If you can then tab-complete the `ros-indigo-...` part of the install command, everything will work fine.
If not, you probably still haven't set this up correctly

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thanks for your reply.
Again I get same error as:
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-uuid-msgs
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-unique-identifier

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-03**:
see edit above.

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
I should say that I have already tried sudo apt-get update.

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
The "rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src -i" gives me
"#All required rosdeps installed successfully"

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
Ok I try to check if the sources set up correctly or not. Thanks again

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-03-03**:
Is `~/catkin_ws/src` your workspace? This obviously needs to be replaced with the directory where you cloned the other sources.
Can you post (edit your question), the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`?

**Comment by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thanks a lot, I tried to source the set up again and used "sudo apt-get update --fix- missing". I could install.
But it's strange as before that package I could install navigation package without any problem!